# Is there any significance to the reuse of the name "Dubauer" in Shards of Honor and Diplomatic Immunity?

Tags: lois-mcmaster-bujold, vorkosigan-saga

Why did Lois McMaster Bujold choose to reuse the name Dubauer in *Diplomatic Immunity*? In the earlier *Shards of Honor*, Dubauer is the name of Cordelia's ensign, while in *Diplomatic Immunity*, Dubauer is the name given by the hermaphrodite passenger on the Komarran ship. They're each significant characters in their respective books. Is there a message conveyed by giving them the same name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what the author has said about this:

> Q: Ker Dubauer in Diplomatic Immunity has the same last name as that unfortunate young man in Shards of Honor (who allowed Cordelia and Aral to have their first experience assisting a profoundly challenged person). I bet you had a reason.
>
> A: Due to founder-effect, Dubauer is a common name on Beta Colony (like Smith); the ba picked it because it seemed bland and unmemorable.

[Source](https://www.goodreads.com/questions/570216-i-wish-there-was-a-way-to-search-your).

Comment: Good to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Not that I know of.  But Ensign Dubauer was Betan, and Ker Dubauer was pretending to be Betan.  For all we know, it's a fairly common family name there.

Comment: Accepted your answer, thanks! Although I was hoping for some subtle and shadowy connection.

Comment: +1. We know from the notes to *The Dreamweaver's Dilemma* that one of the founders of Beta Colony had that last name, and that Ensign Dubauer is descended from him; it would make sense that there would be a lot of other Betans with the same name.