# What is the relationship between Taura and Admiral Naismith?

Tags: lois-mcmaster-bujold, vorkosigan-saga

I have read most of the [suggested background](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2231/1359) materials leading up to *Mirror Dance*, which I am currently reading.

However, I have missed "Labyrinth" (as well as *Ethan of Athos*).

So my first introduction to Taura was Mark's first introduction to her.  I was surprised by the kiss she gave Mark, the implication that a date between her and "Admiral Naismith" would not be unusual, and the implication that she and Miles may have been lovers.

I looked up her entry in the [Vorkosigan Wiki](http://vorkosigan.wikia.com/wiki/Taura) (and got some spoilers that I wished I had missed).  The wiki does, in fact, say that Taura and Miles were friends and part-time lovers.

Yet at the time of *Mirror Dance*, Miles still clearly has a very close relationship with Ellie Quinn (although I don't recall if it was mentioned that the level of intimacy between them was the same as it had been during *Brothers in Arms*, which is the title I read immediately prior to *Mirror Dance*).

So what is the relationship between Miles and Taura, exactly?  Does Quinn know about this, and what is her perspective?  Spoilers for events that happen after *Mirror Dance* are acceptable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You pretty much need to read “Labyrinth”. How Miles (as Admiral Naismith) and Taura met is a large part of that story. Here's what happens in “Labyrinth”:

> Taura is the last survivor of an experiment to produce super-soldiers conducted on Jackson's Whole. She is used to being considered inhuman due to her highly unusual appearance. Miles is thrown into a prison cell with her, with the expectation that she'll kill him and probably eat him (she is being starved). Miles being Miles, he talks her out of it — and specifically, he “proves that he considers her human” by having sex with her.

Miles has an on-off relationship with Taura throughout his relationship with Ellie, up until the point when he meets Ekaterin (i.e. *Komarr*). As far as I recall, Ellie and Miles don't discuss exclusivity. It is highly unlikely, with them being at close quarters, that Ellie would not be aware of Taura and Miles's relationship, though Taura and Miles only hook up in Ellie's absence.

Ellie Quinn is one of the major characters in *Ethan of Athos* but that book has little influence on future events in the series. On the other hand, “Labyrinth” is an important part of the background to *Mirror Dance*, both for Taura and for Miles's history with Jackson's Whole.

Comment: Yeah, I'm kicking myself for only remembering that question about the reading order after getting into *Mirror Dance* (although in fairness, I bought a bunch of the compendiums a while ago, and they've been sitting in my "to read" pile for ages). Finding some of the older titles in print has been a challenge, too, which is why Labyrinth was missed. Thanks for the answer; I'll try a bit harder to find reasonable copies of the missing backstories.

Comment: @Beofett you can get it as an e-book for $5 (as part of the omnibus *Miles, Mystery and Mayhem*) at Baen's site: http://www.baenebooks.com/p-279-miles-mystery-and-mayhem.aspx

Comment: Other than the telling Ekaterin that the relationship with Rowan was "brief" (last ch. of *Komarr*), implying the Elli **and** Taura relationships were substantially longer, what evidence was there that Miles continued "shopping in the company store" with respect to Taura after "Labyrinth"? Perhaps "sometime-lover" ("Winter Fair Gifts") meant 'occasional' rather than 'at some time', particularly with "Also especially valued, I understand."? Also, Mark probably correctly diagnosed Miles as having difficulty saying "no".

Comment: Nevermind, the first chapter of *Mirror Dance* basically states (excitement about Quinn's absence, a kiss, calling him "lover") that Taura was a sexual partner when Elli was not around.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton From memory (ha!) as I'm not near the books right now: Miles and Taura travel together in *Memory* and they spend the journey together. The book after *Memory* is *Komarr*, and starting there Ekaterin is Miles's exclusive love interest.

Comment: At the end of Memory, Elli asks about Taura: "So . . . did you sleep with her?"

His response: "'Um . . .' He swallowed. 'She was before your time, Elli.' After another minute he was compelled to add, 'And after, from time to time. Very rarely.'"

Answer (score 5):

In Chapter 2 of *Memory*, Miles fights nastily with Elli about his falsifying his report to ImpSec.  (Among other things, he says "Don't be such a damned cast-iron bitch!") When she asks who he'll take as a bodyguard on his return trip to Barrayar, he says:

> "I'll...take Sergeant Taura.  That ought to be enough bodyguard to
> satisfy the most paranoid ImpSec boss.  And she's certainly earned a
> vacation."
>
> *"Oh! You!"* It was seldom indeed that Quinn ran out of invective.  She turned on her heel, and stalked to the door, where she turned back and snapped him a salute, forcing him to return it.  The automatic door, alas, was impossible to slam, but it seemed to shut with a snake-like hiss.

This suggests that Elli suspects the relationship and the significance of his taking Taura on "a vacation".

In Chapter 3:

> Miles had long thought that she [Taura] was one of the most beautiful women he had ever seen in her own way....Miles could enumerate every rare occasion they had ever made love, from their very first encounter, six, seven years ago now?  From before he and Quinn had ever become a couple, in point of fact.  Taura was some kind of very special first for him, as he had been for her, and that secret bond had never faded.
>
> Oh, they'd tried to be good.  Dendarii regs against cross-rank fraternization were for the benefit of all, to protect the rankers from exploitation and the officers from losing control of discipline, or worse.  And Miles had been quite determined, as the young and earnest Admiral Naismith, to set a good example for his troops, a virtual resolve that had slipped away...somewhere.  After the umpteenth we've-lost-count-again time he had been almost killed, perhaps.
>
> Well, if you couldn't be good, at least you could be *discreet*.

After he relieves her of duty and they have sex, he muses:

> He thought a bit guiltily of Admiral Naismith's other lover, the public and acknowledged Quinn.  Nobody had to explain or execute being in love with the beautiful Quinn.  She was self-evidently his match.
>
> He was not, exactly, being unfaithful to Elli Quinn.  Technically, Taura predated her.  And he and Quinn had exchanged no vows, no oaths, no promises.  Not for lack of asking; he'd asked her a painful number of times.  But she too was in love with Admiral Naismith.  Not Lord Vorkosigan.  The thought of becoming Lady Vorkosigan, grounded downside forever on a planet she herself had stigmatized as a "backwater dirtball," had been enough to send space-bred Quinn screaming in the opposite direction, or at least, excusing herself uneasily.

Comment: Taura come to Miles' wedding in 'Winterfair Gifts', and finds another admirer.